# Simplify my C# Linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

class :

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

List

```
List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();
```

Datatable :

```
 DataTable dt = GetFromDb ()....
```

I want to fill `lst` with records from `dt`.

I've managed  doing :

```
Array.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray(), y = > lst.Add(new Foo()
{
    Id = int.Parse(y["id"].ToString()), Name = y["name"].ToString()
}));
```

question :

1. Can't I do something else like  `dt.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => fill lst )` ?

*I **know** that part of the  select signature (in this case ) is `Func<datarow,void>` which wont compile*

But still ,  is there any other way of doing this *besides* the ugly way of mine ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977):

```
var foos = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           select new Foo()
           {
              Id = row.Field<int>("id"),
              Name = row.Field<string>("name")
           };

// create a new list
List<Foo> lst = foos.ToList();

// update: add items to an exisiting list
fooList.AddRange(foos);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
var fooList = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable() 
         select new Foo { Id = t.Field<int>("Id"), 
                          Name= t.Field<string>("Name") }).ToList();
```

The [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension method on a DataTable will return a Collection of DataRows. then you do a projection from your Linq Result with required fields. Since it is dataRow type, you need to specify what each column type will be.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, you can do the following:

```
lst = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(y = > new Foo()
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(y["id"]), Name = y["name"] as string
}).ToList();
```

EDIT: **To add to an existing list**

I would normally just concatenate two lists:

```
lst = lst.Concat(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(...)).ToList();
```

However having seen ken2k's answer, I think I will now start using `AddRange` instead.

Comment: nice. What if I want to add items to an existing list ? ( not asked in question - I know)

Comment: You must foreach over the list. Linq is a querying language for getting data, it is not well suited to processing inside the query.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
List<Foo> lst = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => new Foo
{
    Id = int.Parse(z["id"].ToString()),
    Name = z["name"].ToString()
}).ToList();
```

EDIT:

If you want to append to an existing `List<Foo>` instance:

```
lst.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => new Foo
{
    Id = int.Parse(z["id"].ToString()),
    Name = z["name"].ToString()
}));
```

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? To the downvoter: at least you could explain **WHY**...

Answer (score 1):

I got another solution via Rows property :

```
 List<Foo> results = (from DataRow myRow in dt.Rows
                               select new Foo()
                            {
                              Id =int.Parse( row["id"].ToString()),
                              Name = row["name"].ToString()
                             }).ToList();
```